# Invalid json error when trying to post to web server using CN1 javascript port

Tags: codenameone

I get an error 400 from parse.com when trying to post data using the javascript CodenameOne port. The same code works fine in the simulator and mobile app versions.

I followed the Chrome debugging steps mentioned [here](http://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-javascript.html#debugging) and it's pretty hard to see what's happening. I see though that the parse4cn1 logging is identical to that on the simulator except that the latter succeeds whereas the javascript call fails:

*Log from javascript port:*

```
[parse4cn1] Data to be sent: {"data":{"timestamp":1457471857989,"mood":2,"user":"WQpcT5uzxM"}}
[parse4cn1] Request URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Mood
[parse4cn1] Raw response (as string): {"code":107,"error":"invalid JSON"}
```

*Log from simulator:*

```
[invokeAndBlock2] 0:0:18,928 - [parse4cn1] Data to be sent: {"data":{"mood":2,"user":"WQpcT5uzxM","timestamp":1457472171236}}
[invokeAndBlock2] 0:0:18,928 - [parse4cn1] Request URL: https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Mood
[invokeAndBlock2] 0:0:19,348 - [parse4cn1] Raw response (as string): {"createdAt":"2016-03-08T21:22:52.196Z","objectId":"iLrvfxWiYm"}
```

Any idea what might be going wrong and/or how I can debug this problem in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

The above problem disappeared after I hosted the corresponding .war generated by the CN1 build server on open shift (based on [this](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-getting-started.html) tutorial). So I guess it had to do with the preview html file... strange... but it works now.